# How to integrate other ember app to existing project?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I am working on ember cli version 1.12 and node js version v0.12.7,I want to intergrate ember-cli-barcode addon.I have tried following:

ember install:npm ember-cli-barcode

Then it will show message that it required node version 4 >.So I have used Node version v7.0.0 stable.I installed node modules and addon.

Then tried following command:

npm install
bower install
ember server

But It will always shows errors,of node-modules etc.Kindly help me for the same how to integrate addon and which file need to change.

Comment: um, updating to ember 3.0 or 2.18 is not an option? because It could be that this addon is simply incompatible with your old ember version.

Comment: You could change this title to "Add a modern ember cli addon to a pre-cli project" or something.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I can't comment yet.  I'm the author and it's compatible with Ember 2.4 onward. I will be putting version compatibility information in the readme.

I haven't worked with a cli version this old but ember install should be all you need if it's compatible.  The add-on is a really thin wrapper around JsBarcode, so you could use the library direct if you have stay with the current ember version.

Answer (score 0):

To get the benefits of the full ember-cli ecosystem, you'd have to be using the versions that support it. I *think* that it began in *1.13*

As mentioned, it's highly likely that this addon assumes the standard CLI setup. You *could* [ask the author](https://github.com/maxwondercorn/ember-cli-barcode/issues/1).

Depending on your app complexity, you could do a few different things.

You could use the js library https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode  - (which is what the addon uses)

*OR* you may want to rewrite the app with the latest and greatest - *now*. 1.12 is going to be expensive to keep up / and since you've likely figured out how all the logic should work, then writing it again won't be the hardest part. (this sounds fun, right?) - *and then use the addon*

Which will take longer?